# How to add Google ML Kit dependency to SBT project?

Tags: scala, sbt, google-mlkit

When adding the Google ML Kit dependency to our SBT project, it successfully compiles, yet it cannot resolve imports to the `com.google.mlkit` package.

Here is a sample `build.sbt` file, using `barcode-scanning` as an example:

```scala
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.8"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "test-google-mlkit"
  )

resolvers += "Google Maven" at "https://maven.google.com/"

libraryDependencies += "com.google.mlkit" % "barcode-scanning" % "17.0.2" // % "runtime"
```

This successfully compiles, but we cannot resolve an import to `com.google.mlkit`, with or without the "runtime" flag (as indicated on [the maven repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.mlkit/barcode-scanning/17.0.2)).

`object mlkit is not a member of package com.google`

Is it possible to use Google's ML Kit in a Scala project? What are we missing? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the import problem just change the resolvers to:

```
resolvers += "google repository" at "https://dl.google.com/android/maven2"
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem. The previous resolver already compiles and succeeds, but then we cannot resolve an import to the `com.google.mlkit` package.